# XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document Sitemap Error

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, plugins, sitemap

Our website is using Salient theme in WordPress and we recently discovered this error in our sitemap: "error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document"

We think it might be an issue with the theme or a plugin but we've deactivated plugins and searched the theme and cannot seem to fix the sitemap error.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the sitemap XML file

Comment: Take a few minutes to read [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and as suggested, improve your question.

Comment: Install the advanced [health check plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/), switch to troubleshooting mode, reactivate thing one at a time until it works, then continue until it breaks. Also, turn on PHP error reporting and set WP_DEBUG to true.

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether your problem is that (a) you don't understand the error message, or (b) you don't know what file is in error.